# Failed to load config from https://10.20.1.98/config.js?room=n...', [TypeError: Network request failed

Tags: rocket.chat, jitsi-meet

i am trying to connect jitsi meet server but i am getting this error 
    Failed to load config from https://10.20.1.98/config.js?room=n...', [TypeError: Network request failed]

```
i install rocket.chat and jitsi in local server and want to connect my android rocket.chat app to local server and its text messaging is working fine but when i click on video/audio call it
alert me timeout exception for 30 sec and return a white blank screen and it gives us belowenter image description here error in emulator?

Failed to load config from https://10.20.1.98/config.js?room=nimsss6x5hxtgma9wa2wgcv5ex4pubmkhz9jgyq6mfthwd62rghj7ku', [TypeError: Network request failed]
2020-02-23 10:39:12.614 7152-7680/chat.rocket.android.dev E/unknown:ReactNative: console.error: "[__filename]", "<>: ", "Failed to load config from https://10.20.1.98/config.js?room=nimsss6x5hxtgma9wa2wgcv5ex4pubmkhz9jgyq6mfthwd62rghj7ku", {}, stack:

we use self signed certificate (invalid certificate) and i can access config.js file in web browser.
rocket.chat version 3.5.0
```

Comment: hey, have to get any solution?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not using rocket.chat but in case you can manipulate your app, this could be one way to make it work:

I see, your have your own internal server and you have to install a root certificate on your phone to connect to your server.

If so, you have to do the following things:
Add `android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config"` to the application tag in your Android Manifest and create the corresponding file to:
`app/src/main/res/xml`

This is the Content of the `network_security_config.xml` file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<network-security-config>
    <debug-overrides>
        <trust-anchors>
            <certificates src="system" />
            <certificates src="user" />
        </trust-anchors>
    </debug-overrides>
</network-security-config>
```

So your App knows to use the installed certificate, otherwise it will use the platform Default.

I have to say, this problem appears to many developers, so there could be other solutions, like I found with jitsi-meet. 
But this is the way it worked for me.

Hope it helps.